# What do you do when you finish a project?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have just about completed my first Arduino project using an Arduino Uno board, but is that what I use inside the finished device? I figured I’d keep the Uno for future projects and have something else controlling the finished product. Are you supposed to just keep purchasing the Uno board every project?

I just got it a couple of days ago so I’m not very familiar with any of it. If that is the case do you use the batter for power since I can’t have it connected to my laptop once it’s done.

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/product/arduino-prototype-plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options, so it all ends up depending on your personal
preferences:

- You could indeed dedicate this Arduino to this project, and buy a new
  one for the next project. This may be the simplest solution, if not
  the cheapest. Just make sure you are not using a breadboard for the
  other parts. A “proto-shield” may be a good option for soldering the
  rest of your circuit in a permanent form.
- You may replace the Uno with a smaller Arduino, like the Micro (but
  beware it uses a different MCU) or a Pro Mini clone (same MCU). These
  smaller boards can then be soldered onto a PCB using standard 0.1” pin
  headers.
- You could buy a cheap clone, test it to make sure it works as intended
  on this particular project, and dedicate the real one for further
  prototyping.
- You could get a bare ATmega328P plus crystal and caps and put them,
  together with the rest of your circuit, onto a perf-board or a
  strip-board. C.f. Michel Keijzers’ answer. Note that if your program
  can run happily off a somewhat inaccurate 8 MHz clock, you can
  use the MCU's internal oscillator instead of a crystal.
- If your program is far from using all the resources of the Uno, you
  may consider a smaller MCU. The ATtiny85 is a popular “minimalistic”
  choice. Make sure an Arduino core is available for it, unless you want
  to program all low-level.
- For the most professional result, you could design and order a real
  PCB for your whole circuit, including the MCU.

Comment: Regarding your fifth point: There are many people who have made available Arduino "cores" for the ATtiny85:  [ATtinyCore by Spence Konde](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) seems to be well-regarded. It does introduce a lot of extra options in the tools dialog. . [ATtiny by David A Mellis](https://github.com/damellis/attiny) is simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’m brand new to this so have no knowledge but I knew I could count on SE.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

- Buy the main IC (Atmel 328P)
- Use some external components to get it working (like a crystal). Check this on a breadboard to see if it works (and check.
- Buy a case to put it in
- Buy some protoboard or PCB to solder it on (or use a footprint)
- For power, use some components (voltage regulator) or an adapter, or battery, whatever you need. Make sure you check this on a breadboard before you solder it.

If you want to read more about the subject, search for 'prototyping'.

Comment: I particularly like [Adafruit's high quality proto-boards](https://www.adafruit.com/product/571) for my one-off builds. There are several sizes but the 1/2-breadboard size I linked to is the size I use most.

Comment: They seem very easy to convert from breadboard to proto board. If you have no space constraints,  those are probably the easiest.